# Angular service worker doesn't work in sub directory

Tags: angular, manifest, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have created a new angular project and added @angular/pwa, I can't figure out how to get the service worker to work when the website is in a directory. I tried adding the folder to every link in ngsw-config.json and adding a dot before the links (which worked to make the angular app to run in a folder by using `<base href="./">`).

Editing the staturl in manifest.webmanifest to `"start_url": "/folder/"` made the app installable in chrome but it is still not available offline (HTTP ERROR 504).

Versions:
Angular CLI: 8.3.8
Node: 10.16.3
@angular/pwa: 0.803.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25055#issuecomment-408073162
I had to replace ngsw-worker.js

Comment: Did you get this working @1058u4 ? If so would you mind sharing the steps required? Eg. whatever values you had to set such as cope, start_url etc. I still can't get offline to work with /folder, even using the replacement ngsw-worker.js Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I was inactive on this account. I am sure you already found a solution or moved on by now but for everyone with the same problem:

I also added a registration strategy to the ServiceWorkerModule in the file src/app/app.module.ts: `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),`

I hope this helps!